# Transparent Background for UITextView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview

All,

I am populating a UITextView with text from a database. The UITextView sits on top of a background image. I would like to remove the white box that the text is living in so that only the text appears on top of the background image. I did not see anything in the Apple Developer docs for UITextView. Is this possible? Do I need to use a different type of view?

Comment: Looks like using a label instead of a UITextView will work. Is that best?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All `UIViews` have `backgroundColor`. I haven't tried this, but does `tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` not work?